# How to Prove that if $a^n$ is an eigenvalue of $M^n$, then $a^{1/n}$ is an eigenvalue of $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It's trivial to prove that if $a$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $a^n$ an eigenvalue of $M^n$

Is the other way hold as well?

Comment: I hope you can't, because it's very false! :)

Comment: or basically, is it possible that $M^n$ has more eigenvalues than $M$? I can't think of a proof

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general : consider the permutation matrix M such that $M_{i,j}=\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}$ where $\sigma$ is the circular permutation ($\sigma(i)=i+1$).

Then $M^n=I$ and every vector is an eigenvector of $M^n$, but this obviously doesn't holds true for $M$.

On the other hand you have conditions under which this is the case, the most trivial one is for example when M is diagonalisable with $M^n$ having distinct eigenvalues (EDIT : This is unclear. $M$ being of size k, you must have $k$ distinct eigenvalues for $M^n$). So if you are in a particular case, you have to be more specific.

Comment: Or consider a 90° rotation of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: How about this version then?

Answer (score 0):

The revised version is correct as long as you allow complex eigenvalues, and as long as you interpret $a$ as *some* $n$th root of $a^n$. The proof is the direction you already know.

Comment: any general hints on the proof?

Comment: Yes, it's as I said: It follows from the direction you know. List all the complex eigenvalues of $M$; then their $n$th powers are all the eigenvalues of $M^n$.

Comment: By the way, since some answer(s) address your first version of the question and some the second, it makes more sense to leave the first version and then add an **Edit**.

Comment: well, that works if we already know the eigenvalues of $M$, but what I have trouble with is the converse, starting from $M^n$, I can't prove if $M^n$ has n eigenvalues, then $M$ must also has n. Or how can I?

Comment: First of all, you're confusing two meanings of $n$. Say the matrix is $m\times m$. Working over $\Bbb C$, the characteristic polynomial of degree $m$ always has $m$ roots, counting multiplicities.

Comment: yeah, true. But still, doesn't solve the problem right?

Comment: Yes, it does. I suggest you work some examples.